Laravel Admin and User multi login
AuthController.php, authenticate function
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->all();

    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email:dns',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|max:16'
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = Auth()->user();
        $usertype = Auth()->user()->usertype;

        Auth::login($user);

        if ($usertype == 'user') {
            return redirect('/');
        } else if($usertype == 'admin') {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    }
    return back()->with('loginError', 'Login Failed');
}

Login Route
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'authenticate']);

Users Migration
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('surname');
        $table->char('nik');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('conpass');
        $table->string('usertype')->default('user');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

Hello. I am trying to create an auth where if the usertype is admin, it will go to /dashboard. I have added the usertype in database but it still kept redirecting to / page. Can anyone tell me where did I go wrong or is there something I missed? Thank you in advance.

check 'userType' is correctly updated on the DB

use dd() to check what you are getting in $usertype.

Do you add a row in the table or do you change 'user' to 'admin' in 'usertype' column?

you can do a mutch better work here.. for example: $credentials = $request->all(); after validate(), you validate first then bring the request. 2nd don't do 2x  Auth()->user(), use the $user on here $usertype = $user->usertype;. 3rd make a new table user_types so you have and (id,description).ps: remember that default usertype in db is 'user' so when you create a new user it will go to `.

Have you read the documentation related to Laravel guards?
Because Laravel uses guards for multi-login, which allows your application to have multiple types of users logged in simultaneously.
One of the problems that not using guards creates is that imagine a user has both admin and regular user accounts.
If this user has two tabs open in a browser, logging in as a regular user in one tab and as an admin in the other, the app gets confused and cannot determine if the logged-in user is an admin or a regular user.
Here's the link to the documentation on Laravel guards: link
Also, if you're interested in learning and improving your code, consider studying enums in PHP and request validation classes in Laravel.
